# How to seek a file to form a text in desired pattern

Tags: r

Hi I have a file that looks like this -

```
00
01
56
16
43
83
6

00
01
58
90
41
09
 6
```

Now I want a R program to change this to `0001561643836` `0001589041096`..
Please help

Comment: Please try to solve the problem yourself before you ask about how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example showed,

```
 v1 <- readLines('file.txt')
 #or
 #v1 <- scan('file.txt', what='', blank.lines.skip=FALSE, quiet=TRUE)

 indx <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(v1==''),
        values[!values]<- seq_along(values[!values])))
 res <- unname(tapply(v1[v1!=''], indx[v1!=''], FUN=paste, collapse=''))
 res 
 #[1] "0001561643836" "0001589041096"
```

Or

```
 res <- unname(tapply(v1, cumsum(c(1, abs(diff(v1=='')))),
         FUN=paste, collapse=''))
 res[res!='']
 #[1] "0001561643836" "0001589041096"
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(list(v1))[,paste(V1, collapse="") ,rleid(V1=='')][V1!='']$V1
 #[1] "0001561643836" "0001589041096"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scan

scan("filename.txt", sep="\n")